# undefined value in semantic-ui input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have simple from which i used semantic-ui-react to create it :

```
  <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
          <Form.Field>
            <Input placeholder="From ..." type="text" ref="from" />
            <Label pointing>please enter valid email adress</Label>
          </Form.Field>
          <Divider />
```

now i cant access to value's of the input. here is my code:

```
  from: this.refs.from.value
```

it's all undefined.how can fix this ?

Comment: At any point during the code is returning something from either `this.refs.from.value` or `this.refs.from`. I'd start by checking that first.

Comment: @Rodrigo no nothing.

Comment: Did you try what Alexander suggested in His answer?. Perhaps keeping track of the input's state using `onChange` would allow you to get the data from the component's `state`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use `Form` and related components in the [controlled way](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), because most of SUIR components are functional, so they [don't support](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html) refs. I've a [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/34r60x37xp) to show it in action. There is also [example](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form#form-example-capture-values) in docs.